# Character limitation in text item field in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a TEXT item field - order number, where user can enter his details.

When a user enters order number starting with 1, the character limit  should be restricted to 14.

When a user enters order number starting with 2, the character limit  should be restricted to 11.

How can we do it in Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click `Create Dynamic Action`, set following properties:

- `Event` - `Key press`
- `Selection Type` - `Item`
- `Item(s)` - name of your item
- `Condition` - `Javascript expression` with following expression (where `P_ITEM` is name of your item):

  ```
  ($v('P_ITEM').length >= 14 && $v('P_ITEM').substring(0,1) == '1') ||
  ($v('P_ITEM').length >= 11 && $v('P_ITEM').substring(0,1) == '2')
  ```
- `Action` - `Cancel Event`

P. S. I have not tried to copy and paste long values. Probably, you need some additional javascript code for that. Also, this code can't restrict values starting from other symbols.

P. P. S. Also it is possible to do with Validations (it is quite simple, but validations are processed on the server side) and in triggers (both solution use PL/SQL code).

Comment: Nice solution. Wouldn't have occurred to me to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) Logic Worked:)